# Peek and Pop for iPhone XR and iPhone XS

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

I want to add a peek and pop feature to my application. I managed to do it, but now I want to add support for iPhone 5s and iPhone Xr, in which there is no 3D Touch.

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available {
        registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: messagesTableView)
    }
}
```

If I understand correctly, the only way is to implement it with long press.

1. Can I force call `peek` for non 3D touch devices without implementing all action, blur, etc?
2. Can I call native (default) peek and pop for non 3D touch devices when users long pressed? (haptic touch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PeekPop framework](https://github.com/marmelroy/peekpop) which provide backward compatibility for Peek and Pop.

Haptic Touch can be generated via [UIFeedbackGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifeedbackgenerator) subclasses.

Comment: Seems quite unnecessary to use a framework for this. 

Take a look at this post: 
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-add-peek-and-pop-to-a-uitableview

Instead.

Comment: @nullforlife that does not support iPhone 5, iPhone XR, or iPhone 11. So again, third party libraries are needed